# 同一テンプレート内にてURLの動的変更について

Tags: python, django

```
<p>カテゴリー</p>
<ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'index' category.slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<p>場所</p>
<ul>
    {% for location in locations %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'index' location.slug %}">{{ location.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

というリンクがあり、categoryをクリックして遷移した先のページURLは/category/だとします。
この状態でlocationをクリックしてURLを/category/location/としたい場合､

```
<li><a href="{% url 'index' category.slug location.slug %}">{{ location.name }}</a></li>
```

とすればいいのですが、こういった動的なURLの生成を実現するためにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

***Updated***

ソースコードも全て載せます。テンプレートも少し詳しく記載したので御覧ください

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    @property
    def dispatch(self):
        # parent が nullであれば親カテゴリなので自分自身を返す
        if not self.parent:
            return self
        # そうでなければ親カテゴリ(parent)を返す
        else:
            return self.parent

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Location', related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    @property
    def dispatch(self):
        # parent が nullであればStateなので自分自身を返す
        if not self.parent:
            return self
        # そうでなければState(parent)を返す
        else:
            return self.parent

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def filter_category(self, category):
        if not category.parent:
            # Big Category であれば、childrenのカテゴリに所属するPostをfilter
            return self.filter(category__in=category.children.all())
        else:
            # Small Category であれば、categoryに所属するPostをfilter
            return self.filter(category=category)

    def filter_location(self, location):
        if not location.parent:
        # State であれば、childrenのlocationに所属するPostをfilter
        return self.filter(location__in=location.children.all())
        else:
            # Region であれば そのlocationに所属するPostをfilter
            return self.filter(location=location)


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    objects = PostQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^all-categories/$', views.all_cat_index, name='index'),
    url(r'^all-categories/(?P<loc>[-\w]+)/$', views.all_cat_loc_index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<cat>[-\w]+)/$', views.cat_index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<cat>[-\w]+)/(?P<loc>[-\w]+)/$', views.cat_loc_index, name='index'),
]

def all_cat_index(request):
    big_cats = Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)
    states = Location.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)

    c = {
        'big_cats': big_cats,
        'states': states,
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', c)

def all_cat_loc_index(request, loc):
    location = get_object_or_404(Location, slug=loc)

    c = {
        'big_cats': Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True),
        'state': location.dispatch,
        'posts': Post.objects.filter_location(location).all()
    }
    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', c)

def cat_index(request, cat):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=cat)

    c = {
        'big_cat': category.dispatch,
        'states': Location.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True).all(),
        'posts': Post.objects.filter_category(category).all()
    }
    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', c)

def cat_loc_index(request, cat, loc):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=cat)
    location = get_object_or_404(Location, slug=loc)

    c = {
        'big_cat': category.dispatch,
        'state': location.dispatch,
        'posts': Post.objects.filter_category(category).filter_location(location).all()
}
    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', c)


{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block left %}
<p>[カテゴリー]</p>
<ul>
    {% if big_cat %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'classifieds:index' param %}">{{ big_cat.name }}</a></li>
        {% for small_cat in big_cat.children.all %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'classifieds:index' param %}">{{ small_cat.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for big_cat in big_cats %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'classifieds:index' param %}">{{ big_cat.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}


</ul>

<p>[フィルター]</p>
<ul>
    {% if state %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'classifieds:index' param %}">{{ state.name }}</a></li>
        {% for region in state.children.all %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'classifieds:index' param %}">{{ region.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for state in states %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'classifieds:index' param %}">{{ state.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<ul>
    {% for post in posts %}
         <li>{{ post.title }} | {{ post.category }} | {{ post.location }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

つまり

```
<a href="{% url 'index' big_cat.slug %}">{{ big_cat.name }}</a>
```

をクリックして遷移するページは/category/で、このときにこのリンクを

```
<a href="{% url 'index' big_cat.slug state.slug %}">
```

というように、big_cat.slugがすでに含まれている状態に動的に変化させたいです。

Comment: このテンプレートは、サイドバーか何かで、複数のページで共有されていて、**今現在表示されてるURL** によって、**リンクを貼るURLを変えたい** みたいなことがしたいんでしょうか？

Comment: その通りです。まさにそれがしたいのですが説明がうまくできませんでした。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/71728

Comment: 解決済みであれば自己回答ができるので、お願いします。